# Unable to assign data to nsmutableDictionary or nsdictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

In the code below I just assign string value that has been return form the api call. Assign the string value into the `loginResultArray` in the 3rd line which has been declared in the .h file. After that when I move that array into dictionary in the 4th line the dictionary value not stored. When I moved the values are not stored in the dictionary. Can any one please answer me?

```
NSDictionary *resultDict=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
loginResultArray=(NSMutableArray*)[parser objectWithString:jsonValue];
NSMutableDictionary *dict=(NSMutableDictionary *)[loginResultArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the property of loginResultArray retain, synthesize it and then do the following:

```
self.loginResultArray=(NSMutableArray*)[parser objectWithString:jsonValue];
```